# Breakpoints not being hit Mono For Android (Monodroid)

Tags: xamarin.android

My monodroid application builds and runs fine, but breakpoints are not being hit. This is both for physical devices and the emulator.

I created a new default monodroid application and it does hit break points.

I have tried rebuilding, restarting ADB, and rebooting.  I am running VS2010, M4A version 4.0.1.

The android device logging screen gives the following (this covers 3 debug sessions)
Eye friendly version [MonoDroid-Debugger Specific](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20210444/log.txt).  **EDIT** Entire log as requested [Full Log](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20210444/fullLog.txt)

*8:55 AM W 2477 MonoDroid-Debugger Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0i:8907,server=y,embedding=1
8:55 AM W 2477 MonoDroid-Debugger Accepted stdout connection: 36
9:19 AM W 2738 MonoDroid-Debugger Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socketjoglevel=0,address=127.0.01:8913,server=y,embedding=1
9:19 AM W 2738 MonoDroid-Debugger Accepted stdout connection: 36
9:27 AM W 2803 MonoDroid-Debugger Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socketjoglevel=0,address=127.0.Oi:8915,server=y,embedding=1
9:27 AM W 2803 MonoDroid-Debugger Accepted stdout connection: 36
9:27 AM W 2838 MonoDroid-Debugger Not starting the debugger as the timeout value has been reached; current-time: 1326468477 timeout 1326468463
9:29 AM W 2878 MonoDroid-Debugger Not starting the debugger as the timeout value has been reached; current-time: 1326468544 timeout 1326468463
9:29 AM W 2896 MonoDroid-Debugger Not starting the debugger as the timeout value has been reached; current-time: 1326468544 timeout 1326468463
9:29 AM W 2923 MonoDroid-Debugger Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socketjoglevel=0,address=127.0.01:8901,server=y,embedding=1
9:29 AM W 2923 MonoDroid-Debugger Accepted stdout connection: 36
9:29 AM W 2959 MonoDroid-Debugger Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socketloglevel=0,address=12700.1:8901,server=y,embedding=1
9:29 AM W 2959 MonoDroid-Debuqqer Accepted stdout connection: -1
9:29 AM W 2982 MonoDroid-Debugger Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transpoft=dt_socketjoglevel=0,address=127.0.0i:8903,sen’er=y,embedding=l
9:29 AM W 2982 MonoDroid-Debugger Accepted stdout connection: 37
9:30 AM W 3038 MonoDroid-Debugger Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8963,server=y,embedding=1
9:30 AM W 3038 MonoDroid-Debugger Accepted stdout connection: 36
9:32 AM W 3071 MonoDroid-Debugger Not starting the debugger as the timeout value has been reached; current-time: 1326468730 timeout: 1326468676
9:32 AM W 3113 MonoDroid-Debugger Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8965,server=y,embedding=1
9:32 AM W 3113 MonoDroid-Debugger Accepted stdout connection: 37*

Following the advice given [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.mono.monodroid/1639) I took a look inside the apk and I do see .mdb files.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Can you post the whole log somewhere?  It looks like the debugger is connecting properly, but I can't see what else the application is doing.

Comment: Sure thing. Edited original post or you can go here [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20210444/fullLog.txt)

Comment: To clarify, you do see a .mdb file for each of your assemblies, correct?  Also, we just released a new version today, it might not hurt to give it a shot.  http://android.xamarin.com/Releases/Mono_for_Android_4/Release_4.0.3

Comment: Yes the mdb files are there for all 3 assemblies I have the source code for.  I installed 4.0.3 and my project is now back to breaking on the breakpoints as is should.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Mono for Android 4.0.3 and everything is back to normal.  This doesn't really pin down what was broken... but I'll live with it.  Thanks for your help jpobst.