# Mono Debug Symbols missing in apk

Tags: android, visual-studio, debugging, mono, breakpoints

since upgrading the Mono for Android SDK to any version following 4.2.7 breakpoints in Visual Studio are not getting resolved any more, whilst the debugged app itself is running fine.

This particular issue has already been discussed on the Mono for Android mailing list [here](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/debugging-in-Visual-Studio-w-1-9-1-td4899373.html), [here](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Breakpoints-suddenly-stopped-working-td5126366.html), [here](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/debugger-breakpoints-4-4-41-td5712641.html) and also over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853313/breakpoints-not-being-hit-mono-for-android-monodroid), but does not seem to be resolved.

From my point of view it looks like the **.mdb** files necessary for debugging with breakpoints are missing in the generated (and signed) .apk, because they can not be found in either the directory **\obj\Debug\assemblies** or the directory **\obj\Debug\android\assets**. The .mdb files are being generated besides the .pdb files in the \bin\Android directory, but do not make their way onto the device.

I'm not sure if there's something broken in the build process and if the issue could be resolved configuration-wise.

Any help will be appreciated :)

P.S. Neither the project is built in Release mode nor the 'Fast deploy' option is enabled. Linking takes place for 'Sdk assemblies only' and 'Use shared runtime' is enabled. Starting a new project doesn't resolve the issue either, only downgrading MfA to 4.2.7 works for me.

Comment: Is this a Debug or a Release build? Debug symbols are not added to Release builds by default, and Debug builds (when fast deployment is enabled) don't add them to the .apk either, they copy onto the target in `/data/data/@PACKAGE_NAME@/files/.__override__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried [another Monodroid mailist post](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monodroid/2011-September/006512.html) from Sep 2011.
Seems as if it's the linking. I switched linking "Sdk only" to "None" and debug symbols are in the .apk again (*.dll + *.mdb from the \bin\Android directory).

Debugging using breakpoints works, but it would be interesting to have clarified under which circumstances Linking breaks the deployment of a debuggable configuration.