# Xamarin: OnStop, OnPause, OnDestroy never called

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have breakpoints on all these overrides in my activity and no matter what happens, switching to another activity etc, they are never called?

Am I missing something here?

I am using ActionBarSherlock as my base activity if that matters?

Comment: Try tracing them instead of breakpoints. Sometimes the debugger is strange and does not hit breakpoints. If they are still not hit, then there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of mono you are using but this guy fixed his break point problem with a simple mono version change or re install.

[Breakpoints not being hit Mono For Android (Monodroid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853313/breakpoints-not-being-hit-mono-for-android-monodroid)

**How to reinstall mono:**

[Downgrade Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850141/downgrade-xamarin-android/18901213?noredirect=1#comment27930732_18901213)

Comment: Using fast deployment - in debug mode... I'm trying to isolate the problem now...